# PInvoke problem

Tags: c#, pinvoke

This is the signature of the native c method:

```
bool nativeMethod1
(unsigned char *arrayIn,
unsigned int arrayInSize,
unsigned char *arrayOut,
unsigned int *arrayOutSize);
```

I have no idea why arrayOutSize is a pointer to unsigned int but not int itself.

This is how I invoke it from C#:

```
byte[] arrayIn= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
uint arrayInSize = (uint)arrayIn.Length;
byte[] arrayOut = new byte[100];
uint[] arrayOutSize = new uint[1];
arrayOutSize[0] = (uint)arrayOut.Length;

fixed (byte* ptrIn = arrayIn, ptrOut = arrayOut)
{
    if (nativeMethod1(ptrIn, arrayInSize, ptrOut, arrayOutSize))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False");
    }
}
```

and some `DllImport` code

```
[DllImport(@"IcaCert.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateCert2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]<br>
public unsafe static extern bool CreateCert2WithArrays(
        byte* data, uint dataSize,<br>
        byte* result, uint[] resultSize);
```

According to the documentation, native method should return arrayOut fulfilled with the values depending on arrayIn. If its size is less than needed, it returns false. True otherwise. I figured that it's needed 850 elements in arrayOut. So, when I create new byte[100] array, function should return false, but it always returns true. WHY?

Comment: Why are you using unsafe code and fixed. That's not needed here.

Comment: but I use byte* pointer, it's needed to be unsafe, moreover, this part byte* ptrIn = arrayIn requires fixed.

Comment: You don't need to use `byte*` - see my answer

Comment: You can't use the *fixed* keyword to generate pointers that you pass to native code, the array isn't pinned.  David's declaration is correct.  Debug the native code with Project + Properties, Debug, Enable unmanaged code debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need unsafe code and fixed here. The standard P/Invoke marshaller is more than up to the task:

```
[DllImport(@"IcaCert.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateCert2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool CreateCert2WithArrays(
    byte[] arrayIn, 
    uint arrayInSize,
    byte[] arrayOut,
    ref uint arrayOutSize
);

byte[] arrayIn = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
uint arrayInSize = (uint)arrayIn.Length;
uint arrayOutSize = 0;

CreateCert2WithArrays(arrayIn, arrayInSize, null, ref arrayOutSize);
byte[] arrayOut = new byte[arrayOutSize];
CreateCert2WithArrays(arrayIn, arrayInSize, arrayOut, ref arrayOutSize);
```

I don't know for sure what the protocol of the function is, but it is normal for such functions to be able to receive `NULL` if the output array has size 0.

Comment: I know it will work, mine also works for normal arrayOutSizes. But what I'm curious is why it doesn't work if the arrayOutSize is less than needed. It should return false, but it doesn't. I checked it on C++, and it always returns false if arrayOutSize is less than needed. I have no idea.

Comment: native code is right, I tested it with java and c++, only c# fails

Comment: As Hans says, your original code was wrong. The code above is how to do it. Start from this and work forwards.

Comment: Don't you need to set the MarshalAsAttribute.SizeParamIndex attribute on arrayIn & arrayOut?

Comment: @Simon I don't think so since the allocation is done on the C# side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an array is what you're looking for.  It's a pointer to the size of the array, not a pointer to an array of sizes.  Try this:

```
[DllImport(@"IcaCert.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateCert2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public unsafe static extern bool CreateCert2WithArrays(
byte* data, uint dataSize,
byte* result, ref uint resultSize);

byte[] arrayIn= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);

uint arrayInSize = (uint)arrayIn.Length;
byte[] arrayOut = new byte[100];
uint arrayOutSize = (uint)arrayOut.Length; 
CreateCert2WithArrays (arrayIn, (uint) arrayIn.Length, arrayOut, ref arrayOutSize);
uint[] arrayOutSize = new uint[1];
arrayOut = new byte[(int)arrayOut];
CreateCert2WithArrays (arrayIn, (uint) arrayIn.Length, arrayOut, ref arrayOutSize);
```